# Guice with Guava eventbus

Tags: java, guava, guice, event-bus

I am using Gauva event bus to publish events in out rest api. The eventbus is injected using Guice.

```
@Singleton
public class EventBusProvider implements Provider<EventBus> {
    private final EventSubscriberImpl eventSubscriber;
    private EventBus eventBus;

    @Inject
    public EventBusProvider(EventSubscriberImpl eventSubscriber) {
        this.eventSubscriber = eventSubscriber;
        eventBus = new AsyncEventBus(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        eventBus.register(this.eventSubscriber);
    }

    @Override
    public EventBus get() {
        return eventBus;
    }
}
```

The event subscriber.

```
@Singleton
public class EventSubscriberImpl implements EventSubscriber {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventSubscriberImpl.class);

    @Override
    @Subscribe
    @AllowConcurrentEvents
    public void handleEvent(BaseEvent event) {
        try {
            LOGGER.info(event.getClass() + " event fired");
            event.handleEvent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info("Eventbus subscriber " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The event dispatcher which publishes events to the subscriber.

```
public class EventDispatcher {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventDispatcher.class);
    private EventBus eventBus;

    @Inject
    public EventDispatcher(EventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

    public void postEvent(BaseEvent event) {
        eventBus.post(event);
    }

    public void postAsyncEvent(BaseEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("publishing event ", event.getClass());
        eventBus.post(event);
    }

    public void register(EventSubscriber eventSubscriber) {
        eventBus.register(eventSubscriber);
    }
}
```

I inject events into my service classes, which are then published on the event bus.

```
@Inject
public TokenServiceImpl(TokenEvent tokenEvent,
                        EventDispatcher eventDispatcher) {
    this.tokenEvent = tokenEvent;
    this.eventDispatcher = eventDispatcher;
}

public void doSomeStuffAndFireEvent() {
     //create a token
    tokenCreateEvent.setTokenId(token.getTokenId());
    tokenCreateEvent.setQueueId(token.getTokenQueueId());
    eventDispatcher.postAsyncEvent(tokenCreateEvent);
}
```

When we carry out some load tests on the API, we notice that when the events are fired the event properties like tokenId and tokenQueueId are repeated or duplicated. So if

```
Tokens 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ,6, ..... 30
```

are created in a loop, when the event is fired `2,3,4,5,6` events are lost  we see multiple events fired for tokenId 20. Not sure as to why the other events are lost. Is it a problem with Guice injection?

Comment: Well, you use an `AsyncEventBus`. Do you expect one event to be fired exactly when you post it? Then you should use an `EventBus`, not an `AsyncEventBus`...

Comment: No i do not expect the event to be fired exactly when i post it, the events can fire i any sequence. But when the event is fired and executed, we store an entry in DB, this does not seem to work for all events fired. Some entries are missing.

Comment: You should probably write a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us understand your issue.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I suspect your issue is with injecting the event directly... If you're reusing TokenService it's reusing the event reference so later calls are overwriting the ID. Inject `Provider<TokenEvent>` instead.